# How to automatically trigger the pipeline in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

Finally i have succeeded to run the pipeline but now the issue is that I have to manually run the pipeline after every push or commit, is their any way to trigger the pipeline automatically after every push or commit. It would be very helpful. Thank you

```
image: node:latest
services:
- mysql:latest
- redis:latest
- postgres:latest
cache:
paths:
- node_modules/
test_async:
script:
 - npm install
 - node ./specs/start.js ./specs/async.spec.js
test_db:
script:
- npm install
 - node ./specs/start.js ./specs/db-postgres.spec.js
```

Comment: Can you post your `gitlab-ci.yml` file please? It should be done automatically unless you've made some changes as far as I'm aware.

Comment: thank God someone has replied ... i use simple by default nodejs template. I have added .yml file

Comment: I don't see why it's not working.. what happens if you add the a stage called `test` in, as seen in that [example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/nodejs/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml)?

Comment: as i said it is by default format

Comment: what i was trying to do is simply trigger a pipeline

Answer (score 0):

If you add the gitlab-ci.yml file to your project it should be running automatically after a push. If you want to check your CI, use

> yourgitlaburl/ci/lint

it will tell you if the syntax is correct and explain your CI.

Also your CI is not correctly indented:

```
image: node:latest
services:
- mysql:latest
- redis:latest
- postgres:latest
cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/
test_async:
  script:
  - npm install
  - node ./specs/start.js ./specs/async.spec.js
test_db:
  script:
  - npm install
  - node ./specs/start.js ./specs/db-postgres.spec.js
```

Comment: yes i know that it will run automatically but in my case it wasn't. I also did a check using clint and it shows no error.